# Play Framework does not apply Evolutions in Production mode

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, deployment, playframework

I recently deployed my Play App to a Heroku-Server. Running the App in Production-Mode leads to the following Error for each db-table:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:ERROR: relation "tablename" does not exist
```

**Procfile**

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/myApp -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -DapplyDownEvolutions.default=false -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

I had the same issue deploying the app on another (non-heroku) server. Solved it there by first running in dev-mode to apply the schema and then switch to production.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for having the `-DapplyDownEvolutions.default=false` in your Procfile command? I'm not sure how that might interact with the `-DapplyEvolutions.default=true`...it might be worth trying without it.

If that does not work, you could run the evolutions in a one-off process like so:

```
$ heroku run bash
...
~$ ./target/universal/stage/bin/myApp -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -DapplyDownEvolutions.default=false -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

Once that completes, you're other dynos should be good to go. However, this creates a period in which the app is deployed, and the evolutions have not been run.